# Using HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-4.5, httpclient

Are the following two methods, `getData1Async()` and `getData2Async()` are essentially the same? If so why don't I need `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` in `getData2Async()` method?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string uri = "https://www.blahblah.com/getdata";
            Task<string> x = getData1Async(uri);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x.Result);
            Task<string> y = getData2Async(uri);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(y.Result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static async Task<string> getData1Async(string uri)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    static async Task<string> getData2Async(string uri)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getData1Async - here you are getting the object of type HttpResponseMessage and if you don't ensure that response has completed successfully and call response.Content.Read..., the answer will be indeterministic.
getData2Async - directly calls httpClient itself to get the string which internally makes sure that it only returns when data has been received.